# How do I install Ubuntu Server using Daemon Tools instead of a disc?

Tags: server, dual-boot, windows

How do I install Ubuntu Server using Daemon Tools instead of a disc?

Just trying to see if it can be done, and if so how can I do that? I'm looking to Dual Boot it with Windows 8 as well.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi James, welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Looks like the dual boot part of your description is a different question -- could you remove it from this and ask it as a new question?

Answer (score 0):

Given that Daemon Tools is Windows software and ubuntu server replaces it, no: you cannot install Ubuntu server using daemon tools instead of a disc.