# Can I Dual Boot Ubuntu from a Virtual CD drive?

Tags: dual-boot, virtualization

My Computer Sciences professor told me to dual boot Ubuntu on my computer, to get some experience with the Linux operating system. However, my DVD drive is broken and my BIOS will not boot from a USB drive. My professor is telling me that I can dual boot from a virtual CD drive, like Daemon Tools, but from all the research I have been doing I haven't seen anything stating that this can be done. Which would make sense since the Virtual CD drive would not be detected on boot up as it is run on the Windows OS.

Can anyone confirm or deny this for me?

Answer (score 1):

[This post says it's not possible](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259567/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-server-using-daemon-tools-instead-of-a-disc), but it is very well possible to run Ubuntu with Virtual Box in a virtual machine. It's probably best to install i386 for performance reasons.

Download Virtual Box here:
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

After starting Virtual Box, you can place the iso file in the virtual drive for the installation of the Ubuntu OS. After you are done installing, remove the iso before you reboot the virtual machine.

Your Virtual machine connects to virtual ethernet regardless of if your host machine uses WiFi or not.